# Можно ли использовать тег figure для карточек с изображениями/галереи изображений?

Tags: html5, семантика

Есть такой код:

```html
<section class="main__content">
                <figure class="main__card">
                    <div class="main__card-container">
                        <img src="img/mercury.jpg" alt="Mercury" class="main__card-  img" width="196" height="137">
                    </div>
                    <figcaption class="main__card-desc">Mercury</figcaption>
                </figure>

                <figure class="main__card">
                    <div class="main__card-container">
                        <img src="img/venus.jpg" alt="Venus" class="main__card-img" width="196" height="137">
                    </div>
                    <figcaption class="main__card-desc">Venus</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <!--  И так далее -->
</section>
```

Верно ли я использовал figure и figcaption?

Answer (score 0):

Тег `section` предполагает использование что-то из заголовков `h2` и тд... А вообще такую галерею создать можно. Лучше конечно использовать обычный `img` который будет в ul>li но это на любителя. Если вы верите в свои силы и тетко понимаете в чем разница между заполнений `alt` и `figcaption`, то можете использовать.